# Storing every iteration of dictionary comprehension in new nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Apologies for redundancy, been trying to make this work for 3 days.

I can't figure out how to store a new dictionary inside my nested dictionary.

```
for team, roster in team_roster.items():  
 stats['rp'][team] = {}
 for player in roster:
    if player in rp_year_STD[1]:
        stats['rp'][team] = {stat_type: stat for stat_type in p_stat_type for stat_list in rp_year_STD\
for stat in stat_list if stat_list[0] == stat_type}
```

Tried this, does exact same (1 duplicate dictionary for each team):

```
for team, roster in team_roster.items():  
 stats['rp'][team] = {}
 for player in roster:
     if player in rp_year_STD[1]:
         for stat_type in p_stat_type:
             for stat_list in rp_year_STD:
                  if stat_list[0] == stat_type:
                     for stat in stat_list:
                       stats['rp'][team][stat_type] = stat
```

Team is a string key in separate dictionary (team_roster, shown below)
roster is a list of strings/player names for each team.
Player is string in list of strings (roster).
rp_year_STD is a list of lists. rp_year_STD[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuT5f.png) is a list of strings/player names.
p_stat_type is a list of strings that validates the keys in the resultant dictionary (rp_year_STD is a list of lists compiled from a spreadsheet, the title of each column is potentially a key in the resultant dictionary).

I understand I'm creating 1 dictionary with this dictionary comprehension.

What I want is to create a new dictionary for each player that's included in roster and rp_year_STD and store it in the corresponding team dictionary, but I'm just creating 1 identical player dictionary (which is of course consists of the key/value pairs from the last entry in rp_year_STD or row in the spreadsheet the data comes from) for each team dictionary.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, truly appreciate all of the information posted here. Thank you.

Here's what rp_year_STD is, each column being a list within a list and rp_year_STD[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuT5f.png) being a list of strings/player names.

[image: Here's what rp_year_STD is, each column being a list with a list and [1] being the name of each player which may or may not be included in player list]

Here's the list of keys that I'm comparing against the column header/[0] index of each list. I don't want each column/list item/value to be in the resulting dictionary, which is why I validate with the list p_stat_type (shown below):

```
p_stat_type = ['Name', 'TBF', 'H', '2B', '3B', 'R', 'ER', 'HR', 'BB', 'IBB', 'HBP', 'SO', 'AVG', 'OBP', 'SLG', 'wOBA', 'playerId',  'K/BB', 'HR/9',\
           'K%', 'BB%', 'K-BB%', 'AVG', 'WHIP', 'BABIP', 'LOB%', 'FIP', 'xFIP', 'playerId' 'GB/FB', 'LD%', 'GB%', 'FB%', 'IFFB%', 'HR/FB', 'IFH%', 'BUH%', \
               'Pull%', 'Cent%', 'Oppo%', 'Soft%', 'Med%', 'Hard%', 'playerId']
```

Here's the duplicate dictionary that being put in each [team] key:

```
'CHC': {'Name': 'Emmanuel Clase', 'TBF': '89', 'H': '19', '2B': '5', '3B': '1', 'R': '8', 'ER': '6', 'HR': '2', 'BB': '4', 'IBB': '0', 'HBP': '1', 'SO': '21', 'AVG': '0.226190476', 'OBP': '0.269662921', 'SLG': '0.38095238', 'wOBA': '0.2757020506', 'playerId': '21032'}
```

Very close to working, but this is just the last value for each list in rp_year_STD.

Here's the team_roster dictionary, the function team_roster returns a list of strings\current players for each team :

```
team_roster = {'ARI' : team_roster(ARI, 'Diamondbacks'),
'BAL' : team_roster(BAL, 'Orioles'),
'BOS' : team_roster(BOS, 'Red Sox'),
'CHC' : team_roster(CHC, 'Cubs'),
'CIN' : team_roster(CIN, 'Reds'),
'CLE' : team_roster(CLE, 'Indians'),
'COL' : team_roster(COL, 'Rockies'),
'DET' : team_roster(DET, 'Tigers'),
'HOU' : team_roster(HOU, 'Astros'),
'KC' : team_roster(KC, 'Royals'),
'LAD' : team_roster(LAD, 'Dodgers'),
'WSH' : team_roster(WSH, 'Nationals'),
'NYM' : team_roster(NYM, 'Mets'),
'OAK' : team_roster(OAK, 'Athletics'),
'PIT' : team_roster(PIT, 'Pirates'),
'SD' : team_roster(SD, 'Padres'),
'SEA' : team_roster(SEA, 'Mariners'),
'SF' : team_roster(SF, 'Giants'),
'STL' : team_roster(STL, 'Cardinals'),
'TB' : team_roster(TB, 'Rays'),
'TEX' : team_roster(TEX, 'Rangers'),
'TOR' : team_roster(TOR, 'Blue Jays'),
'MIN' : team_roster(MIN, 'Twins'),
'PHI' : team_roster(PHI, 'Phillies'),
'ATL' : team_roster(ATL, 'Braves'),
'CWS' : team_roster(CWS, 'White Sox'),
'MIA' : team_roster(MIA, 'Marlins'),
'NYY' : team_roster(NYY, 'Yankees'),
'MIL' : team_roster(MIL, 'Brewers')}
```

team_roster(teamA, 'TeamA') would be ['A. Man', 'A-Jax']

Again, thanks all for any suggestions.

Comment: (1) What should be the keys in the team dict for the players? The player name? (2) If "roster" is a list of lists then "player" would be a list.

Comment: maybe you should create list and `append()` to list - `stats['rp'][team] = []` before loop, and `stats['rp'][team].append( {stat_type: ...} )`. OR maybe you shouldn't use dictionary compression but normal loop and `stats['rp'][team][stat_type] = ...` OR maybe you should use `player` as a key `stats['rp'][team][player] = {stat_type: ...}`

Comment: @ Michael Butscher {'Name': 'Emmanuel Clase', 'TBF': '89', 'H': '19', '2B': '5', '3B': '1', 'R': '8', 'ER': '6', 'HR': '2', 'BB': '4', 'IBB': '0', 'HBP': '1', 'SO': '21', 'AVG': '0.226190476', 'OBP': '0.269662921', 'SLG': '0.38095238', 'wOBA': '0.2757020506', 'playerId': '21032'} that dictionary is whats being added to each [team] once. Sorry, of course player is a list, a list of players for each team, will update.

Comment: @furas So, 1. when I use the list.append it's just creating a list of duplicate dictionaries. 2. I think you're right that I shouldn't use comprehension, but I don't know how to write that loop. 3. I originally tried using player as a key, but it's the same result, just with an added nest and the the player is included in the keys of the dictionary I'm trying to create for several hundred players.

Comment: Also, thank you both for your suggestions.

Comment: in dictionary comprehension you doesn't use `player` to get only values for selected player. Maybe you should use `rp_year_STD[1][player]` instead of `rp_year_STD`

Comment: @furas The comprehension is returning a dictionary in the correct format, but just one dictionary with identical key/values from the last item of each list in rp_year_STD list of lists.

Comment: @furas  So because it's returning the key/values of of the last items, I think I just need a way to say stop, store this in a new dictionary, then go to the next index of each list. Does this make sense? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know your data so I can't anwser. You should add some data to question andmaybe minimal working code and then we can see what is the problem and we can test ideas.

Comment: If `rp_year_STD` is a list of lists then `rp_year_STD[1]` is a list of non-list objects (strings?), right?. If `player` is a list then `if player in rp_year_STD[1]:` can't be true ever because a list can't be an item in a list of non-list objects.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm sorry for my lack of detail.  Player is a string in roster, which is a list of lists, all strings (player names). rp_year_STD [1] is a list of strings (player names), column B in the screenshot of spreadsheet I just posted. The dictionary I posted after your last comment is all the values I want from the final row that spreadsheet or last index in each list of rp_year_STD. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @furas Hey, the final solution of my problem implemented your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by 1. using the player as a key, as @furas suggested - thanks for your time! 2. referencing the index of the the player in the dictionary comprehension and removing the nested loop from the comprehension and adding as normal loop as, again, @furas suggested. So, hopefully this has some use and/or I receive some informed suggestions for improvement. Thanks, below is code I ended up with:

```
  for team in team_roster.keys(): 
  stats['hitter'][team] = {}
  for player in sort_roster(team)[0]:
      if player in h_zips[0]:         
          h_zips_index = h_zips[0].index(player)
          index = h_year_STD[1].index(player)
          if h_zips[1][h_zips_index] == team and h_zips[25][h_zips_index] == h_year_STD[23][index]:
              stats['hitter'][team][player] = {}
              for stat_list in h_year_STD:
                  player_dict = {stat_type: stat_list[index] for stat_type in h_stat_type if stat_list[0] == stat_type}
                  stats['hitter'][team][player].update(player_dict)
```